# Is there a Java class I can override to inspect and modify all network requests as they go out?

Tags: java, http, networking

I would like to implement custom retry logic for all failed HTTP requests in my Java applications without having to modify all the networking code. Is there a class or interface I can implement that would force all outgoing requests through a method that I could inspect the request and response?

A related example from another project is a custom [TrustManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html) implementation I used to handle revocation status for our internal CA PKI. I'm wondering if there is anything related that could be used to centrally manage HTTP behavior.

Comment: Look for wireshark

Comment: Not trying to be a self-pitying forum poster, but what's with all the downvotes? :-) I would honestly love to hear people's thoughts on why this question is problematic. Asking good questions is something I'd like to get better at.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that on the source code level.

You see, the corresponding "data" doesn't "travel" through a specific unique **instance** of any class. Depending on your protocol, all kinds of classes, such as `java.net.Socket` will be instantiated over time. You can of course look into what code you wrote is doing, but you have no chance **changing** the behavior of such existing standard classes on the source code side.

The only things that might help:

- looking into debuggers, for example by identifying methods that matter to you, to then set breakpoints there
- using instrumentation. Meaning: you hook into JVM startup, and add/manipulate classes at runtime